# The integral of $\tan x$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

I am  a very slow learning person in math. I am trying to learn integration but I can't find the best way to start solving an integral.

Now I am trying to solve

$$\int \tan x\, dx$$
but I dont know how I should start! Can someone provide any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$ \int {\sin x \over \cos x}\,\mathrm dx$$

Now you can use this substitution:

$$u=\cos x \quad \mathrm du=-\sin x\,\mathrm dx$$

Comment: You confused $\cos^{-1}$ with $\sec$ when it actually means $\arccos$

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor I think the person who asked question got it what I wrote.

Comment: How many "sock-puppet accounts" have you created, to post question you ask from other accounts, so that you know how to answer, from "shere" account, and then upvoted and accepted from one or more other accounts you created as well.  Alas, the suspension.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $\tan x =\dfrac{ \sin x}{ \cos x}$ and $(\cos x)'= - \sin x$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int \tan x\, dx=$$

$$\int \frac {\sin x }{\cos x } dx =$$

$$ \int \frac {-du}{u } =$$

$$\ln |sec (x)| +C$$

Answer (score 0):

with the last hint, consider $d(\cos x)=-\sin xdx$